# How to store explored nodes in ROS?

Tags: ros, exploration, rosbag, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using nav2d to explore a map. Is there any way I can store the order of explored nodes in a data structure?

I was thinking we can whether I can use rosbag for this somehow. Please let me know if anyone knows about this

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220321/how-to-store-explored-nodes-in-ros?/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-11-04**:
What do you want to achieve? All nodes are published on a Marker topic, but this list is more or less unordered.

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-11-04**:
I want to check the overlap in the algorithm. So, I want to have the order of explored nodes, so that I can track what path the robot followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see how this could be done out-of-the-box. But the pointclouds that are attached to the nodes should have a sequence number or at least a timestamp, that can be used to order them. But you would have to find a proper way to output them via ROS.

Another way might be to wite a very simple node, that regularly logs to robot's pose via TF.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-11-05**:
Yes, that's a great idea, I can write a node to log the robot's pose through tf_listener. But, I am not sure, how can I trace the position back to the specific occupancy grid cell. Is there any way where I can relate a position with the cell number?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-11-06**:
I don't think so. The grid map is dynamically created from the laser scans and the corrected poses from the slam-backend whenever get_map is called. Such a relation would even change with an optimization run of the backend after a loop was closed.